# Show loading div after submitting ANY form

Tags: submit, loading

I know how to show a submit after submitting a form. But I would like a loading div to appear after ANY submit on the page. The same that happens on PHPMyAdmin.

Can anyone please help? How do I trigger to load a div after a submit?

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this just call the function from an onclick event in your submit button.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form method="post" onsubmit="myFunction()">

<div id="showDiv"></div>

<script>
function myFunction() {
document.getElementById("showDiv").innerHTML = "Here is my div.";
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks but I want it so that it happens anytime when a form is submitted. Basically without  onclick="myFunction()"

Comment: Then you can add it to the onsubmit in your form tag like this

Comment: Not really want I want. I want it when the page is loading after a submit. Makes sense?

Comment: are you wanting it on a seperate page?

Comment: Only way I can describe it is that I want it like PHPMyAdmin. There, when you click on a link or submit something a loading box pops up until the other page loads.